# Problems with VMware

Tags: vmware

I am starting a Linux class and the teacher provided download links for VMware and Fedora. When I made a new virtual machine I get two errors and it doesn't work. I have an HP Envy 360 and it is 64bit. . [image]

Comment: Is the version of _Windows_ you are running 64-bit?  Are you attempting to run a 64-bit ISO in a _container_ that's set to be 32-bit?

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled the virtualization features of your CPU? This would be Intel-VT or AMD-V. You will have to go into your BIOS/UEFI and enable this setting.

Since you say that you have an HP computer to access the BIOS you need to restart the computer, press the <kbd>F10</kbd> key as the computer turns on. Alternatively you can press <kbd>Esc</kbd> then <kbd>F10</kbd>

Once you are at the BIOS you can navigate to **System Configuration** then select **Virtualization Technology** and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Select **Enabled** and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> again.

After you have verified that Virtualization Technology is enabled press <kbd>F10</kbd> select yes and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to save the changes and reboot.